# How to remove a particular file from a git commit which has been pushed to remote repo?

Tags: java, git

I'm a newbie to git and programming. I want to remove a file added by mistake in a commit in Git. I did few more commits after that. Is there any way to undo my mistake?

Here is the scenario. I added a file  named 'MYFILE' in my first commit, and I did 3 more commits after that. Is there any way to revert the fist commit and remove 'MYFILE' , without any damage to other files in that commit or commits after that. I found many thread regarding reverting a commit I couldn't understand any of them. Can any one help me to solve my issue in a simple manner.

Comment: If it's not very problematic that it remains in history, the most painless solution would be to just create a new commit with the file removed and push that. Editing history can end up being rather painful, especially in repos shared with other people.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Thank you for replying.  can u help me with little more clarification?  Are you suggesting me to go and revert my first commit, then remove the file I wanted to remove, then commit it? If I do so will it affect my other commits?

Comment: FIX YOUR ALL-CAPS.

Answer (score 2):

(This is an answer to the exact question asked. If that is the best solution is another issue.)

There are no pure technical problems with modifying the history and republish something that already was published. The challenge is that doing so will introduce extra work and potential problems for the other people that interacts with the repository.

If you think that the other people using the repository are technically skilled enough to cope with it, or you give instructions for how to adjust or you think maybe no-one else is using the repository you might go ahead<sup>1</sup>.

---

> Is there any way to revert the fist commit and remove 'MYFILE' , without any damage to other files in that commit or commits after that.

Yes. So assuming no modified files, the branch is `main` and that `git log --oneline` produces the following:

```
49a6628 (HEAD -> main) Some other changes
4ed7bd5 Some more changes including modifying MYFILE
ee7648a Some changes
5852cce First commit, creating MYFILE as well as other changes
```

(If you have not modified MYFILE since it was created you can ignore that part but I include that scenario for completeness.)

So the simplest approach here would be to create a new commit that removes MYFILE and then move that commit back in history and conflate it with the commit that introduced in the first place:

```bash
git checkout main
git branch main.backup    # Optional, but branches costs nothing and better safe than sorry
git rm MYFILE
git commit -m "Remove MYFILE"
```

The way to do the commit history shuffling is with [interactive rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase/). It takes as an argument the commit to start from, not including (e.g. parent of the first commit you want to modify) which does not work for the very first commit so for that scenario you need to give the option `--root` instead:

```bash
git rebase -i --root
```

This will open the editor with a list of all the commits like this

```
pick 5852cce First commit, creating MYFILE as well as other changes
pick ee7648a Some changes
pick 4ed7bd5 Some more changes including modifying MYFILE
pick 49a6628 Some other changes
pick c010613 Remove MYFILE
```

Now move the remove commit to follow right after first commit and change pick to fixup (or just f) like this

```
pick 5852cce First commit, creating MYFILE as well as other changes
fixup c010613 Remove MYFILE
pick ee7648a Some changes
pick 4ed7bd5 Some more changes including modifying MYFILE
pick 49a6628 Some other changes
```

When you exit the editor git will start applying the changes. If git encounters some condition that it cannot automatically resolve (in this case that one commit creates a file and the other commit removes it) it will stop and drop you off in the shell with the conflicting commit checked out (e.g. *detached head* mode) and expect you to resolve it:

```bash
error: could not apply c010613... Remove MYFILE
hint: Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
hint: "git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
hint: You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
hint: To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".
Could not apply c010613... Remove MYFILE
```

`git status` will print the following:

```
interactive rebase in progress; onto ec0e5c0
Last commands done (2 commands done):
   pick 5852cce First commit, creating MYFILE as well as other changes
   fixup c010613 Remove MYFILE
Next commands to do (3 remaining commands):
   pick ee7648a Some changes
   pick 4ed7bd5 Some more changes including modifying MYFILE
  (use "git rebase --edit-todo" to view and edit)
You are currently rebasing branch 'main' on 'ec0e5c0'.
  (fix conflicts and then run "git rebase --continue")
  (use "git rebase --skip" to skip this patch)
  (use "git rebase --abort" to check out the original branch)

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
        deleted by them: MYFILE

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Resolving the issue is easy since we just want the file gone:

```bash
git rm MYFILE
git status
...
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        deleted:    MYFILE
```

So with the conflict resolved we tell git to continue with the interactive rebase:

```bash
git rebase --continue
```

Git will open the editor and let you modify the commit message. In this example I change it to just "First commit".

After exiting the editor, once again we get a conflict for the commit that modifies the file after it was removed:

```bash
[detached HEAD 6aff4f2] First commit, creating MYFILE as well as other changes
 Date: Sun Aug 21 12:03:30 2022 +0200
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 .gitignore
CONFLICT (modify/delete): MYFILE deleted in HEAD and modified in 4ed7bd5 (Some more changes including modifying MYFILE).  Version 4ed7bd5 (Some more changes including modifying MYFILE) of MYFILE left in tree.
error: could not apply 4ed7bd5... Some more changes including modifying MYFILE
hint: Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
hint: "git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
hint: You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
hint: To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".
Could not apply 4ed7bd5... Some more changes including modifying MYFILE
```

Same resolution as earlier:

```bash
git rm MYFILE
git rebase --continue
```

After that there are no more conflicts, and the history now looks like

```bash
cbf7dc1 (HEAD -> main) Some other changes
3098241 Some more changes
1938a65 Some changes
408a8b0 First commit
```

Optional but highly recommended: at this point it is a good idea to test the branch with [git-test](https://github.com/mhagger/git-test). You can delete the `main.backup` branch when done.

Since your local `main` branch now has diverged from origin's `main` branch you need to force an update when pushing with `git push -force-with-lease --force-if-includes origin main`.

---

<sup>1</sup> I have done this in the past, http://atinout.sourceforge.net/news.html.

Answer (score 0):

Use `git rm --cached /path/to/file` to remove the pushed file 
Now, update the file like how you want it 
Then add with `git add /path/to/file` 
Then commit the file with `git commit "reverted file"` 
Then push the commit with `git push`

Comment: I did as u said, but it is still visible in my pull request as a removed file. why is that?